# Python field calc syntax error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-joins

The screenshot shows a calculate field tool in modelbuilder.  The error I'm getting is invalid syntax line 1.  I can't see any issues w/the syntax so I'm hoping someone out there can help. It calculates field A to equal field B if field A is not equal to field B.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable names cannot have a dot (.) in it.
Simply change your function to the following:

```
def update(field1, field2):
   if field1 != field2:
      return field2:
   else:
      return field1
```

---

> Python has some conventions for variable names. You can use any
>   letter, the special characters “_” and every number provided you do
>   not start with it. White spaces and signs with special meanings in
>   Python, as “+” and “-” are not allowed.

http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch02s03.html

Comment: ustroetz, thank you for the response.  The calculate field is being done on a joined table where the two joined tables have the same field name(PIPEID).  So I'm calculating table1.PIPEID from table2.PIPEID.  Without the period, how can I differentiate the two fields?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about that and I can't test it (no access to ESRI), but I think you can just leave your expression the way you had it. Only change the Code Block part. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Right, you can name the variables whatever you want within the codeblock function definition, and pass the correct field names to the function in the calculation expression.

Comment: @Steve !WATER.C_WATR_PIPE.PIPEID! gets passed to field1 and !Water_Pipe.PIPEID! gets passed to field2, you still use the update(!WATER.C_WATR_PIPE.PIPEID!, !Water_Pipe.PIPEID!)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm completely green to codeblocks and variables so it took me a little while to figure how to pass along variables in the codeblock.  Didn't realize all I had to do was copy/paste ustroetz's response :)  Have it working now.  Thanks again for the help.